# editing and saving an excel file in R

Tags: r, excel

In an imported excel file, for example iris- If I want to change the name of a Species, from setosa to "newname", how would I do it? and then save it as a new excel file, or a new csv file to be used subsequently. I use this code but it does not recognize the new file iris1.xlsx.
All it does it- is prints newname, but fails to save the modification into a new file.

```
iris %>% 
mutate (Species = case_when(Species=="setosa" ~ "newname")) %>%
write.xlsx(iris, "iris1.xlsx")
```

Comment: I guess your `write.xlsx` should be `write.xlsx(., "iris1.xlsx")`

Comment: Might also be that it needs the full file path.

Comment: In Stack questions, code blocks' fences (three backticks `\`\`\``) must be on their own lines, not shared with any code. I've suggested an edit. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun), you have to replace "iris" (which is the original df) with "." (which is the modified df) in the chaining process.

Code is below with a more complete solution and a base R alternative :

```
## Packages
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)

## Tidyverse
iris %>% 
  mutate (Species = case_when(Species=="setosa" ~ "newname",
                              TRUE ~ as.character(.$Species))) %>%
  write.xlsx(.,"iris1.xlsx")

## Base R
iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)
iris$Species[iris$Species == "setosa"] <- "newname"
write.xlsx(iris,"iris1.xlsx")
```